# "Globalization folders cannot be found" error following upgrade to 8.2.5

Tags: upgrade

I am testing a process developed by a colleague to upgrade my local copy of a client's Sitecore instance from 8.1.3 to 8.2.5.

The site front end comes up fine, as does the back office login screen, but upon logging on, I am getting the error "Globalization folders cannot be found".

I have searched the web quite extensively to try and find out what is going on, and drilled into the decompiled DLLs where possible, but have drawn a blank.

The full exception is detailed below. Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks.

```
    [Exception: Globalization folders cannot be found]
       ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Renderings_Common_PageCodes_PageCode_cshtml.ResolveCultureFolder(String[] cultureNames) +208
       ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Renderings_Common_PageCodes_PageCode_cshtml.Execute() +3330
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343

    [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Renderings/Common/PageCodes/PageCode.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
    ]
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
       Lloyds.Site.Infrastructure.HideOnErrorRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\Lloyds-Update\src\Lloyds.Site\Infrastructure\HideOnErrorRenderer.cs:35
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +196
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +184
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +196
       Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
       ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute() +1060
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343

    [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
    ]
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
       Lloyds.Site.Infrastructure.HideOnErrorRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\Lloyds-Update\src\Lloyds.Site\Infrastructure\HideOnErrorRenderer.cs:35
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
       (Object , Object[] ) +74
       Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
       Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
       Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +196
       Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +332
       System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +37
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below two steps to resolve this issue.

Step 1:- Move source globalization folder and content to the destination

Example -Website\sitecore\shell\client\Speak\Assets\lib\globalize to destination
Website\sitecore\shell\client\Speak\Assets\lib\globalize

I have verified this error that occured in the files located at:- sitecore\shell\client\Speak\Layouts\Renderings\Common\PageCodes\PageCode.cshtml

there is a function wich trying to fetch the content at above path but not able to find out.
[image]

Step2 - Please make sure to provide access to below folder

Try adding the ASPNET user with full control for the folder C:\WINDOWS\Globalization.
~/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/globalize/supplemental/
~/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/globalize/main/

Hope that should resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a bit, please. As it is, this answer is more of a comment size than an answer. We are looking for longer, more detailed answers that really help the OP and future visitors understand, at a minimum, all of the following: what the problem is, why the problem occurs, how to fix the problem and why the fix works. Try addressing each of those in your answer and perhaps provide links to documentation, if appropriate. I'll be happy to upvote your answer once those details have been added.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel - I have added more details, Let me know if required any more information or correction.

Comment: I see your instruction on how to fix the problem, but I still don't see the explanation of why the problem occurs. This is one piece of crucial information that should be included in every post, if possible. Try starting your post with "I have seen this issue occur when ..." or "The problem you are facing is being caused by ..."

Comment: Thank you for looking at this - I did look at adding the ASPNET user as you describe, but for some reason (despite my having admin access to my PC), I could not add this user.

Eventually I did a completely fresh pull of the original code and ran the update process again, which worked - so I am not sure what went wrong previously. If you do identify the cause, it would be great to know what it was, but it is no longer urgent.